# Return paremters of POST request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I send a GET request from Ajax (with jQuery), I can see the URL in the Chrome console as `script.php?param=1`.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "script.php",
    data : {
        q : "save",
        query : query // a variable
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log(status, error);
    }
});
```

When I do something like `var_dump($_GET)` I even get the contents.

But what if I do a equivalent POST request? The URL is shown simply as `script.php` without any parameters. Also how can I return the variables parameters of `$_POST` in this case?

Comment: I guess you would look into some basics of requests. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: If you use `GET`, the parameters will show up in the url. If you use `POST` the will not. That's it. If you want your code to accept both you can use `REQUEST` or check if the values are `POST` or `GET` manually.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes: Yes, but how to access my URL script.php so that I still can see the contents of $_POST?

Comment: If you access the page directly, you will not have the `POST` values. Those values can only come from a previous page which sent them.

Answer (score 1):

The _POST parameters are not meant to be in the querystring, that's why it is POST. You can see them in your browser debugger, on the network tab.

You can print them out on your PHP exactly like the GET parameters.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
echo $_POST["key"];
```

Comment: But how do I access the script.php with the parameters? Simply by `script.php?param=1` works only with a GET request.

Comment: @user1170330 — The code you have in the question does that already.

Comment: @Quentin: Does what? Sorry, I don't know how to (manually) access the script.php when sending a POST request.

Comment: @user1170330 there is no URL that you can copy/paste that works with _POST. That is a GET. You do the _POST programatically with AJaX (like you are doing).

Comment: @user1170330 — Is the question you are trying to ask "How can I conveniently generate POST requests for debugging purposes?"?

Comment: @Quentin: Exactly. I just want to access the parameters for debugging purposes.

Comment: You have a `console.log(data)`, so you should see the output of the script.php in the console tab. In the network tab check the headers to see the parameters sent.

Answer (score 0):

Via comments on other answers:

> How can I conveniently generate POST requests for debugging purposes?

## Using JavaScript

You already have code for this.

Browsers ([Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/),  [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/)) have a set of Developer Tools which include a Network tab that you can use the inspect the request and response.

## Via an HTML form

So long as you only want to generate data in a format that a plain HTML form can generate, you can use one and submit it.

## Via tools designed for making arbitrary HTTP requests

The command line [`curl` utility](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and GUI tool [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) spring to mind.